# Organize content by month? SQL statement?

Tags: taxonomy, date

Using custom content types and custom fields with a pretty standard setup to post the content to the page.

Where I'm having difficulty is trying to organize this content by date. I have a field (below) with months available (eg. Feb-March.) I also have a date/time named field start_month which is not posted. I would like to organize the content by start_month, so items available in Jan will appear in the list first, December at the bottom.

Can this be done with an SQL statement in my query? Is there a simplest solution?

```
<?php 
$thisQuery = new WP_Query(array(
'post_type' => 'my_content'
));
?>

<?php while($thisQuery->have_posts()) : $thisQuery->the_post(); ?>

<div class="box">

<div class="1"><?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail'); ?></div>
<div class="2"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
<div class="3"><?php the_field('description'); ?></div>
<div class="4"><?php the_field('months_available'); ?></div>

</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<?php
endwhile;
endif;
get_footer();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just guessing, but try this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'my_content',
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value',
    'meta_key'       => 'start_month',

    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'    => 'start_month',
        ),
    ),
);

$thisQuery = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: Had to modify field to store month as number value instead of date. Query worked like a charm though, thanks.

Comment: @Mr.Thompson I was actually busy with an answer with that info. There is no logic to sort by month names in custom fields. The only possible solution is to save the month by number, and not name :-)